# Adding two factor authentication in Django/Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I know this topic has been widely discussed, but most of the examples are about two factor authentication in standard Django templates, while in my case i want to add two factor authentication to a project where Django is used as an API on the backend while the frontend is a native VueJS application.

For eveything authentication related, i'm using the built-in Django session authentication, since both frontend and backend are deployed on the same server.

**My question is**: how can i add two factor authentication (using google authenticator or yubikey) to a project where django is used as an API?

**Here is the problem**: the easiest way to do this would be to let the user login from the frontend, and once the user is logged in from `/accounts/login` (built-in django authentication view), submit a form where the user has to input their code. The problem with this approach is that once the user is logged in Django will create a session, so `request.user.is_authenticated` will return `True` even though the user didn't submit the Two Factor code yet, so everything would depend on the frontend. I don't like this approach because i'm afraid that someone might find a way to avoid submitting the two factor form and navigate on the rest of the site (since according to Django that session would be authenticated) without the two factor authentication

**What i tried:** I still have to write most of the code for this, because i want to understand how safe is it first. But here is my approach:

**First approach**

1. User submits the login form
2. Once the login form is submitted, a POST request with the credentials is sent to an endpoint called `/authenticate` in my Django app. This endpoint will use the Django built-in `authenticate()` method that will check if those credentials belong to a user without creating a session.
3. If the credentials belong to a user, it will return `True` to the user. At this point the user will submit a form with the 2FA code, and if the code is right, the request is sent to `/accounts/login` which will check again password and email and actually login the user and create the session, this time.

**Second approach**
Another approach, that would be even better, would be to override the Django-Allauth login view so that i can add a check for the token, so something like (WARNING: pseudo-code):

```
if provided_code == user_code:
   login()
   return HttpResponse({'Result': 'Logged in!'})
else:
   return HttpResponse({'Result': 'incorrect code'})
```

Where `provided_code` is the 2FA code provided by the user and `user_code` is the correct code that i will retrieve from another function like `get_user_2fa_code(user)`.

I'm not a security expert, but i didn't come up with better approaches. How safe would it be? Is there a better way to add 2FA auth to a Django project where django works as a backend API?

[Here is the login view](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py):

```
class LoginView(
    RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView
):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "account/login." + app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION
    success_url = None
    redirect_field_name = "next"

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(LoginView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["request"] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get_form_class(self):
        return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, "login", self.form_class)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        try:
            return form.login(self.request, redirect_url=success_url)
        except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
            return e.response

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
        ret = (
            get_next_redirect_url(self.request, self.redirect_field_name)
            or self.success_url
        )
        return ret

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signup_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(
            self.request, reverse("account_signup"), self.redirect_field_name
        )
        redirect_field_value = get_request_param(self.request, self.redirect_field_name)
        site = get_current_site(self.request)

        ret.update(
            {
                "signup_url": signup_url,
                "site": site,
                "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value,
            }
        )
        return ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help..I'm unsure. Most of the existing django 2fa projects work how you describe- I recommend checking how they do it for some better hints.

1. First check username/password using `django.contrib.auth.authenticate`. This auth's the credentials but won't create a session.
2. If the user has 2FA- route them to a page to do the verification step
3. Once verification step is complete- log them in with `django.contrib.auth.login`

For the login auth view and posting the credentials- I did something like this:

```
class TwoFactorAwareLoginView(TemplateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(data=request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                devices = <something to get your 2FA device blobs>
                if not devices: #no user devices- log them in
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cool-page"))
                else: #2FA devices exist- route them to verification view and perform auth_login once complete
                    # add some context needed for verification view in session or context
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("two-factor:verify-login"))
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This was very helpful and indeed it's very similar to how i'm handling it. I just have one doubt: after you redirect to the 2FA form, how do you check credentials? I mean, how do you know who is submitting the 2FA code?

Comment: I think there are a few different options. You could perhaps generate some cache key to pass around, or add it to the session like  `request.session["user"] = user` to stash the user inside the session data, and fetch it in the view where you do the check.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Here is another way i found to do it: i added a third field called '2fa_code' to my login; then in the login form, if the credentials are right and if the user has 2fa enabled, django returns a JSON response '2fa required', at this point my frontend will open a popup form with a single input where the user submits the same login form but this time only the 2FA code. It's very similar to what you did, except that it doesn't redirect to another page, but maybe i'll do like you did

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to implement multi factor authentication yourself, I'd look at SAML or OAuth. The basic idea on these methods is that your site doesn't ask credentials at all, but you redirect authentication to security providers system and your site get user info you can use to check if user exist in your system (quite often email) and authentication token which you can validate. User get token after all authentication process is passed, not just first phase.

There seems to be heaps of plugins for Django for SAML / OAuth authentication: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/authentication/

And what comes to forcing multi factor authentication, that is setting in authentication provider system, not in your code.

Comment: I think i'm already using what you mean, since Django-Allauth is mentioned on that link and i'm using that module for everything auth related